# how to concatenate a string to a file in a For loop

Tags: linux, bash, console, environment-variables, cat

I need to create files for the user with the words "operating system" inside.  I have tried in many ways but I can't figure out which is the best way, for now, this way is the "best" (it creates the files but is empty)..

```
read n
for i in $(seq $n)
do
     "Operating system" > txt_$i
done
```

Comment: You appear to be doing ["Cargo Cult" programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Also, you are asking for help in solving a student question. You need to solve such problems yourself rather than asking others to provide you with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `echo` or `printf`.

```
echo "Operating system" > txt_$i
```